# Margin is white. How to change it back to the background color?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

[Here is a picture of what I want changed to blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnW5i.png)

here is my html and css code: https://jsbin.com/cofeweqaca/edit?html,css,output

Okay, weird stuff going on. When I created the jsbin to show you all my problem, the problem wasn't there. So my problem exists in sublime somehow. My problem is this: the space in between the 2 grey divs (the top is a jumbotron the bottom is not). Is supposed to be blue like it is in the jsbin. But in my sublime, when I open it up in Chrome, its white. Everything else is blue except that little stripe between the two divs.
 I am VERY new to the web developer scene. So maybe someone wiser than me can explain the reason of this issue? Why is it white? Thanks!

Edit: Here is my code directly.

```css
html {
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
}
#navb {
  background: #3E474C;
}
#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 ul li a {
  color: white;
}
li:hover {} html {
  background: #A5BCCC;
}
body {
  background: #A5BCCC;
}
#rankjumbo {
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 350px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.searchbox {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto auto;
}
#text {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
}
#h1 {
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
#button {
  background: #4B7795;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
}
.list {
  height: 300px;
  background: #eee;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="rankjumbo" class="jumbotron">

  <div class="container">

    <div id="special">

      <h1 id="h1">Rank.gg</h1>

      <div class="searchbox">
        <input id="text" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter your IGN...">
        <button id="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block">See Where You Rank!</button>

      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>

<div class="list">



</div>
```

Comment: You probobably should paste the code directly here ;)

Comment: annnnnnnnd done. Thanks:)

Comment: are you taking about the bottom white space ?? after the list div ??

Comment: I added a picture of me circling the white part that I want to be blue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by moving the bootstrap link above my stylesheet in my html.

Answer (score 0):

it because of the height inside of #rankjumbo and the blank div class "list" remove the css .list and make your #rankjumbo like this [Live Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/0nd0v3rq/3/)

```
#rankjumbo{
margin-top:100px;
margin-bottom: 0;

}
```

Comment: but why is it fine in jsbin and not fine on my end?

Comment: scroll your jsbin output or make a new one .. coz expire is over for your jsbin and one more thing you set whole body background color already 
but on list class you make a height and set a background color white.

Comment: ok i refreshed it. The color i set for  "list" is #eee. which is the grey color. Same color as the jumbotron

Comment: did you set color on #jumborton ?? and #808080 this the grey color code...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/0nd0v3rq/4/ here is the link if i set #808080 as background color for jumbotron and list

Comment: it doesnt matter what color #eee is as long as its not white

Comment: yea no that is not the color i want. i want #eee. Thats not the problem

Comment: The problem is that the blue color between the two divs is not blue when I run the html file with chrome. When I run it in Jsbin it is blue like it should be. The shade of grey of the div is exactly how i want it.

Comment: #ffffff is the closest web-safe color to #eeeeee.. and 
background: #A5BCCC; you set on your whole html and body section. I'm running jsfiddle on chrome.. please click right and select insept and check .

Comment: and which two divs mention the div id or class please

Comment: #eee is the default color for jumbotrons. But those are not the problem. Those are showing up fine. Its the #A5BCCC not showing up. Is that color not websafe? It just doesnt make sense that it will showw everywhere just fine except the middle

Comment: #A5BCCC search this color on spycolor